# remove asterik in Friggeri template

Tags: biblatex, biber, friggeri-cv

- How can I remove the asterisk under *Publicaciones*  section?

[image]

- I have tried:

  1. `\renewcommand{\refname}{}`
  2. `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}`
  3. `\printbibsection{article}{ }`
  4. Compile with biber [option](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv)

**But none works**

This is what I have:

```
 \documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
 \begin{document}
 \section{Publicaciones}
 \printbibsection{article}{\textbf{Art\'iculos}}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice MWE (you might want to mention where to get `friggeri-cv` from, it doesn't seem to be on CTAN). When I run the code above, I don't run into any problems with asterisks. Do you? Which version of `biblatex`/Biber do you use?

Comment: In here: https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/fancy-cv create an account a compile that example and you will get the asterisk

Comment: Did you try running it on a local up-to-date TeX install? Those online services are at times slow with updating and the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `friggeri-cv` class does not seem to provide starred versions of all sectioning commands, but the standard `subbibliography` heading uses `\subsection*`.

If we redefine subbibliography headings to use `\subsection`, all is fine

```
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection{#1}}
```

Comment: you should also make this comment on the link that I share you, I know, for sure, that your comment will help thousands of people. Have a good day!